# MCP3008 raspberry pi ADC error

Tags: c, embedded, raspberry-pi, adc

I am getting an error when reading from the mcp3008 ADC. The function below returns 127 when receiving a 3.3V input. Since it is a 10 bit ADC, it should return 1023.

I have defined my pin numbers correctly, and included both stdio.h and wiringPi.h. Any help is appreciated.

```
int main(void) {

    int adcValue = 0;

    wiringPiSetup();

    pinMode(csPin, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(sclkPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(mosiPin, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(misoPin, INPUT);

    while(1) {
        delay(10);
        adcValue = readADC(CHAN0);
        if (adcValue == -1)
            printf("Error reading from %i \n", CHAN0);
        else
            printf("Chan0: %i \n", adcValue);
    }

}

int readADC(int adcChan) {

    // Variables
    unsigned char dataOut = 0;
    unsigned char adcout = 0;
    int i, j = 0;

    if ((adcChan > 7) || (adcChan < 0)) {
        return -1;
    }

    digitalWrite(csPin, HIGH);

    digitalWrite(sclkPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(csPin, LOW); 

    dataOut = adcChan;
    dataOut |= 0x18; 
    dataOut <<= 3; 

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (dataOut & 0x80) {
            digitalWrite(mosiPin, HIGH);
        } else {  
            digitalWrite(mosiPin, LOW);
        }

        dataOut <<= 1;
        digitalWrite(sclkPin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(sclkPin, LOW);
    }
    adcout = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        digitalWrite(sclkPin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(sclkPin, LOW);
        adcout <<= 1;
        if (digitalRead(misoPin)) {
            adcout |= 0x1;
        }
    } 

    digitalWrite(csPin, HIGH);

    adcout >>= 1; 
    return adcout;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `adcout` is a `char` and can't hold the 10-bit value. Use an `unsigned int` instead. Also, you should not shift back your value with `adcout >>= 1;`, it's already good.

Comment: I'd upvote, if not for the advise to use `int`, which should never be used for bitwise operations. Use an unsigned type instead, preferably `uint16_t` in this case.

Comment: Changing the datatype on adcout did the trick! Still need the adcout >>= 1 tho. The mcp3008 returns a null bit in the least significant position. Thanks!

Comment: @DylanCornell Did you actually test this ? The mcp3008 datasheet clearly states that, out of the 12 bits you read, the first is undefined, the second is null, and the last 10 (least significant) are the value. Which means even the last bit is part of the value.

Comment: @ElderBug I am running the file as we speak, At 3.3V, the value returned from the function is ~1023 and at 0V it is ~0.  It is my mistake, I should have said the first bit is null that is why I shift the value before I exit my function.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a variable  `unsigned char adcout = 0;` which of a size 8 bits NOT 10 bits. Also you are right shifting it by 1 before returning,So most probably you are getting :

```
255 Right shifted by 1 = 127.
```

Answer (score 1):

use python and spidev module!
It will look something like!

```
import spidev

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)

def read(ch):
    adc = (spi.xfer2([1,(8+ch)<<4,0])
    data = ((adc[1]&3 << 8) + adc[2]
```

This should give u proper readings from the mcp3008 chip.
I am currently using this chip in a sensor module for connecting my analog sensors. Ch is the channel on the mcp3008 (0-7)